# Spring boot not direct to correct URL with RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm learning spring boot framework. I copy a sample project from official site and rename the project to SpringTest.In it there is a html like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>My Contacts - Spring Boot Web Application Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Contacts</h1>
    <a href="/list_contact">Click here to list all contacts</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the controller is

```
package com.example.SpringWebT1;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public class AppController {
         
        @RequestMapping("/list_contact")
        public String listContact(Model model) {
             
            ContactBusiness business = new ContactBusiness();
            List<Contact> contactList = business.getContactList();
             
            model.addAttribute("contacts", contactList);       
             
            return "contact";
        }
    }
```

I run the project when I click the button. it goes to localhost:8080/list_contact instead of localhost:8080/SpringTest/home/list_contact which is the correct URL. Is this my tomcat configuraion problem or I missed some step? Thx.

Comment: If you want to hit your controller, change the href on your button to point to /home/list_contact

Comment: @peterchaulaOk.It work now. But if I remove "@RequestMapping("/home")" and it not work again.

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Try adding an http method to your `@RequestMapping` annotation like that `@RequestMapping(path = "path", method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because your JS redirect only knows that your server is running on localhost:8080, so when you tell it to use `<a href="/list_contact">Click here to list all contacts</a>` it appends href to server url which leads to `localhost:8080/list_contact`.

You need to modify your href to:

```
<a href="/home/list_contact">Click here to list all contacts</a>
```

I'm not sure what is `/SpringTest` - is it the server context you configured?

Comment: Ok.It work now. But if I remove "@RequestMapping("/home")" and it not work again. So annote the class with RequestMapping is a must?

Comment: @kkluo Nope :)

When you add @RequestMapping("/home") over the controller class - it appends /home at the start of each endpoint. So it would be /home/list_contact, /home/list_users, /home/login and so on

When you remove "@RequestMapping("/home")" then all the endpoints in controller declared as is, so they would be like: /list_contact, /list_users, /login

If you need your app to be working again - change @RequestMapping("/list_contact") to @RequestMapping("/home/list_contact") OR modify href again to 
<a href="/list_contact">Click here to list all contacts</a>

Comment: SpringTest is the project name.

Comment: Project name does not affect the MVC configuration - so the valid url should be 
localhost:8080/home/list_contact

OR

localhost:8080/list_contact - IF you removed "@RequestMapping("/home")"

Comment: ZharkovI removed the annotation and localhost:8080/list_contact  not work. But localhost:8080//SpringTest/list_contact  work

Comment: Well, I'm not really up to your project config :)
But then I assume localhost:8080/SpringTest/list_contact works for you?

Comment: Yes.but I wonder why it go to localhost/list_contact instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234200/discussion-between-alexzander-zharkov-and-kk-luo).

Comment: Ok. looks like if I run the XXXApplication java and it work. But if I run the project on server it's not.

Answer (score 0):

one question:  do you open the first html from controller?

1、 add `server.servlet.context-path=/SpringTest` to your springconfig file

2、 change the href of   to `/home/list_contact`

Comment: I didn’t. I just run the project in eclipse and it open the url localhost:8080/SpringTest/index